# Automatically pulling key values from fitting function into Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

As the title states, I wish to have some cells that automatically update based on a fitting function that is applied to data that will change based on user input. More specifically, I have some data that I will input, it will generate a fitting function that has an exponential form as shown:

[image: Graph]

And based on the form of the fitting function: `y = A*e^(-kx)`

I want two cells to update with the values of `A` and `k` automatically as the function changes. How can I do this without manually creating the fitting function myself?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I've already manually created a fitting function that matches the one in Excel using the math from this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350754/fitting-exponential-curve-to-data

But again, I wanted to see if this was possible without doing that all by hand and taking advantage more of Excel's built in functionalities.

Comment: You can use LOGEST function.